blender4.1 gltf animation export settings problem
glb/gltf animation export settings are not as straight forward as previous versions. Anyone got tips for settings. The animation is a basic walk cycle from mixamo that needs to be a glb. new texture is attached. any help would be appreciated

Hello and welcome. This site is more geared towards direct questions about solving specific issues. Could you edit your question and rephrase it to illustrate a real use scenario and what specific issues you encountered or what your are unsatisfied with, so we can present an objective answer, rather than "general tips".

For me I would just set the [Animation mode: Active actions merged]
If it doesn't work also check the "Bake All Objects Animations"
I also uncheck "Shapekeys Animation" and "Sampling Animations"
Hope this helps !

perfect you did it man i love you
